# Last Card moving out of height when stacked together

Tags: html, css

I am trying to **stack cards** above each other on scroll using css, all the cards are working as expected, only the last card moves out of height, this issue is probably related to the **height of the cards**, I am just not able to figure it out.

Here is the code

```css
.card{
  height:100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  
}

.card:nth-child(even){
  background-color: blue;
}
.card:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="card">Card One</div>
  <div class="card">Card Two</div>
  <div class="card">Card Three</div>
  <div class="card">Card Four</div>
  <div class="card">Card Five</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused mainly by the default body margin which for most browsers is 8px. On top of that, you used `height: 100vh` and `top: 25px`. SO you will overflow by 25px by default. ontop of that comes the default body margin of 8 px which will the last card offset in total by 33px.

The solution is, to reset the default body margin with `body { margin: 0; }` and then set the top sticky point to 0 with `.card { top: 0; }`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.card{
  height:100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  
}

.card:nth-child(even){
  background-color: blue;
}
.card:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="card">Card One</div>
  <div class="card">Card Two</div>
  <div class="card">Card Three</div>
  <div class="card">Card Four</div>
  <div class="card">Card Five</div>
</div>
```